# Different memtest results on different systems

Tags: motherboard, memtest86+

I wanted to test my systems RAMs and used memtest86+ 4.20. On the first system it show errors when it reached about 40% and in random pattern test for all my RAMs. But when I test those RAMs in my second system, they didn't return any error. Both my systems have GIGABYTE Motherboards, the first with Core i7 CPU and the second with core i5 CPU. If it is needed, first is GA-EX58-UD5 and second is GA-PA65-UD3-B3. RAMs are 1333 both 2G and 4Gb were tested. I checked BIOS and it was on default setting. I wonder if this is motherboard fault or something else!

Comment: Go to Gigabyte's website and check if the memory modules are known as working for your specific motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible the memory controller is bad, or even the CPU.  If you can test the memory on a 3rd system, that would be ideal.  You can call Gigabyte for support, and see what they say.  I have had some manufacturers tell me that it is not uncommon for Memtest86 to give false readings.  And I have seen it happen, too.  Manufacturers often have their own software for testing memory and CPUs.